# Unable to open PDF files in broweser through Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium

I am trying to Automate a web Application through Selenium Web driver using Java in IE Browser. One of the Print Button in Web application navigates to a PDF Page which needs to be validated. However when Automating after the Clicking event opening a Blank page in IE Browser and throwing HTTP-500 Java Lang Illegal Argument. I have to Automate this in all three Browsers(Chrome Firefox and IE) but majorly in IE. Any solutions .

Comment: Show what you've tried so far

Comment: Adding a snippet of your code would also help.